# Simple ajax gives status == 0 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've coded a simple ajax request but it keeps on giving me a status == 0 error. I have checked the var s. It stays true till the end of the validations. The ajax runs beforeSend because i see Happened in dev console then it gives a status == 0 error.. I am currently developing in XAMPP and an somewhat identical type of validation is working but this isn't..

Here's the JS

```
function contact_validations() {

    var name = jQuery('#contactname').val();
    var cemail = jQuery('#contactemail').val();
    var tel = jQuery('#contactphone').val();
    var address = jQuery('#contactaddress').val();
    var message = jQuery('#contactsubject').val();
    var s = true;

    if (name == '' || name == null) {
        jQuery('#name_err').html('Please enter your name');
        s = false;
    } else {
        jQuery('#name_err').html('');
    }

    if (cemail == '') {
        jQuery('#email_err').html('Please enter email');
        s = false;
    } else {
        var x = cemail;
        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
            jQuery('#email_err').html("Please Enter  Valid E-mail Address");
            s = false;
        } else {
            jQuery('#email_err').html('');
        }
    }


    if (tel == '' || tel == null) {
        jQuery('#tel_err').html('Please enter your telephone number');
        s = false;
    } else {
        jQuery('#tel_err').html('');
    }


    if (address == '' || address == null) {
        jQuery('#address_err').html('Please enter your address');
        s = false;
    } else {
        jQuery('#address_err').html('');
    }


    if (message == '' || message == null) {
        jQuery('#message_err').html('Please enter your message');
        s = false;
    } else {
        jQuery('#message_err').html('');
    }


    if (s) {
        var url = "/c/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: "action=contact_email&name=" + name + "&email=" + cemail + "&tel=" + tel + "&address=" + address + "&message=" + message,
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }

            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log('happened');
                jQuery('#ajax-loader').show();
                jQuery('#ajax-loader').html('<img src="/c/wp-content/themes/aussie/images/ajax-loader.gif">');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                jQuery('#ajax-loader').hide();
                console.log(result);

                if (result == '0') {
                    console.log("No Result")
                }
                if (result == '1') {
                    jQuery.fancybox({
                        href: '#contact-popup'
                    });
                    jQuery('#contactname').val('');
                    jQuery('#contactemail').val('');
                    jQuery('#contactphone').val('');
                    jQuery('#contactaddress').val('');
                    jQuery('#contactsubject').val('');

                    console.log(s);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the PHP

```
function contact_email() {



            $url = get_bloginfo('url');
            $storeemail = get_option('contactemailstored'); 
            $to = $storeemail['contactemail'];
            $subject = $url . ' - Contact';
            $name = $_POST['contactname'];
            $email = $_POST['contactemail'];
            $phone = $_POST['contactphone'];
            $address= $_POST['contactaddress'];
            $content= $_POST['contactsubject'];                                         
            $message = '<br>'.'Name:- ' .  $name . '<br>';
            $message  .= 'Email- ' . $email . '<br>';
            $message  .= 'Phone:- ' . $phone . '<br>';
            $message  .= 'Address  :' . $address  . '<br>';
            $message  .= 'Subject  :' . $content  . '<br>';


            $sent_message = wp_mail( $to , $subject, $message ); 



        if ( $sent_message ) {
            // the message was sent...
            echo '1';
        } else {
            // the message was not sent...
            echo '0';
        }

        exit;


    }


add_action('wp_ajax_contact_email', 'contact_email');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_email', 'contact_email');
```

EDIT:

HTML if someone needs

```
<form name="contactemail_form" action="" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="contactemail_form_submitted" value="Y">

                    <div class="contact-form">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <span class="control-wrap ">
                                    <input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" size="40" class="form-control text" placeholder="Name">
                                </span>
                                <span class="enq_err" id="name_err"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <span class="control-wrap ">
                                    <input type="text" name="contactemail" id="contactemail" value="" size="40" class="form-control email"  placeholder="Email">
                                </span>
                                <span class="enq_err" id="email_err"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <span class="control-wrap">
                                    <input type="tel" name="contactphone" id="contactphone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control text " placeholder="Phone">
                                </span>
                                <span class="enq_err" id="tel_err"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <span class="control-wrap ">
                                    <input type="text" name="contactaddress" id="contactaddress" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control text"  placeholder="Address">
                                </span>
                                <span class="enq_err" id="address_err">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="full-width">
                            <span class="control-wrap ">
                                <textarea name="contactsubject" id="contactsubject" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control textarea" placeholder="How Can We Help You?"></textarea>
                            </span>
                                <span class="enq_err" id="message_err"></span><br>
                                <input type="submit" value="send request" class="form-control" name="contactemail_submit" onclick="return contact_validations();">
                                <div  id="ajax-loader"  class="fancybox"></div>
                                <div style="display:none;">
                                  <div class="aussi-en-pop" id="contact-popup"><h3>Thank you for contacting us.</h3> <p>Your <?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' )?> agent will respond to your enquiry within 48 hours.</p></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </form>
```

Comment: are you missing contentType?

Comment: Tip: Instead of else if else if else if everytime, why not use a switch case?

Comment: Thanks for the tip ill try switch case.

I tried contentType. XML and TEXT does not give an error but the result is still being 0..

Comment: Are you sure of the url? Usually a 0 status code means that the url can't be reached.

Comment: Yes i am sure i have used the same in another function and it works fine.. The direct link also works in the browser and the variable url also outputs the correct url..

Comment: i cannot seem too console.log( data ); 

I have a feeling that something is wrong there..

Answer (score 0):

Okay a solution worked for me. I dont know why it was causing the error but what i tried is changing the format of data to a proper JSON. Here is the updated js.

```
function contact_validations(){
event.preventDefault();
var name= jQuery('#contactname').val();
var cemail= jQuery('#contactemail').val();
var tel= jQuery('#contactphone').val();
var address= jQuery('#contactaddress').val();
var message= jQuery('#contactsubject').val();
var s=true;

if(name==''|| name==null ){
    jQuery('#name_err').html('Please enter your name');
    s=false;
    }else{  
        jQuery('#name_err').html('');
        }

if(cemail==''){
    jQuery('#email_err').html('Please enter email');
    s=false;
    }else{ 
        var x=cemail;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
            { jQuery('#email_err').html("Please Enter  Valid E-mail Address"); s= false;} 
            else{
                jQuery('#email_err').html('');
                }
        }   


if(tel==''|| tel==null ){
    jQuery('#tel_err').html('Please enter your telephone number');
    s=false;
    }else{  
        jQuery('#tel_err').html('');
        }



if(address=='' || address==null){
    jQuery('#address_err').html('Please enter your address');
    s=false;
    }else{  
        jQuery('#address_err').html('');
        }


if(message=='' || message==null){
    jQuery('#message_err').html('Please enter your message');
    s=false;
    }else{  
        jQuery('#message_err').html('');
        }
        console.log( url );


if(s)
        {
            var url = "http://localhost:9080/c/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
            var data = {

                "action":"contact_email" ,
                "name": name ,
                "email": cemail ,
                "tel": tel ,
                "address": address ,
                "message": message 
            }
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,   
            contentType: 'JSON',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            beforeSend: function(){
                console.log('happened');
                jQuery('#ajax-loader').show();
                jQuery('#ajax-loader').html('<img src="http://localhost:9080/c/wp-content/themes/aussie/images/ajax-loader.gif">');
                },
            success: function(result) {
                jQuery('#ajax-loader').hide();
                console.log(result);


                if(result=='0')
                {
                    console.log("No Result")
                }
                if(result=='1')
                {   
                jQuery.fancybox({
                    href: '#contact-popup'
                });
                jQuery('#contactname').val('');
                jQuery('#contactemail').val('');
                jQuery('#contactphone').val('');
                jQuery('#contactaddress').val('');
                jQuery('#contactsubject').val('');

                console.log ( s );
              } 
            }
        });


        }




}
```

Comment: the result still points 0. I've created another issue for this. If someone can help please do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423727/ajax-success-returning-0